# how to concatenate the string in AsQueryable to search by the name, by null checking

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search by a `name`, which is the input from the  UI, however, I have the separate fields for the name in the database, which are firstname, lastname and middle initial.

So far what i have tried:

```
var filtered = (from c in _dbContext.Address
                join i in _dbContext.Customers.Where(a => !request.AccountNumbers.Any() || 
                request.AccountNumbers.Contains(a.AccountNum)) on c.FkParent equals i.Id
                select new ContactRequestListModel
                {
                    Id = c.ID,
                    FirstName = c.FirstName,
                    LastName = c.LastName,
                    MiddleInitial = c.MiddleInitial
                });

 var query = filtered.AsQueryable();

if (request.Names.Any())
    query = query.Where(x => request.Names.Contains(x.FullName));
```

**ContactListRequestModel**

```
public class ContactRequestListModel : ContactRequestModel

{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName => string.Join(" ", new string[] { FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName }.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
}
```

The middle initial could be null, so which could add the double spaces while concatenating the string, so I have tried to omit the spaces in the `name`. But this query has given me the error.

> The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the
> query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

I didn't want to convert the query to ToList() and filter by name.

But is there any way to query by null checking the `MiddleInitial` and query as `AsQueryable`. What is the workaround in this case?

Comment: Because your FullName logic cannot be translated to SQL. You need to first load results to memory. Then you can run your expression.

var query = filtered.ToList();

But if there are many records, you may have memory problems.

Comment: how to do with the `IQueryable` without changing it to ToList()?

Comment: var query = filtered.ToList().AsQuerable();

Comment: what is the advantage of converting tolist to queryable again? is there any benefits?

Comment: There is something wrong with your sample code - your reference `x.FullName` but don't define `FullName` in your query. You really should re-write to do the where before the select.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use + operator:

```
public string FullName {
      get {
         return FirstName + MiddleInitial ?? "" + LastName ;
      }
}
```

Comment: still, it says it couldn't be translated